Can the union of Smith–Volterra–Cantor set and a zero measure set on $\mathbb R$ contain an interval?
Let $C$ denote the Smith–Volterra–Cantor set, which is no-where-dense but with positive Lebesgue measure. I wonder if there exists a Lebesgue null set $N$ such that $C\cup N$ contains an interval on $\mathbb R$.
If so, I would like to ask a more general question --- if I could replace $C$ by any subset $E$ of $\mathbb R$ with positive measure and ask if $E\cup N$ could contain an interval.
I am inclined to believe that $C\cup N$ cannot contain an interval no matter what null set $N$ one picks. But I don't know how to prove it.

NO. A nowhere dense set (regardless of any other attribute it may have) has the property that each (nondegenerate) interval contains a (nondegenerate) interval that is contained (as a subset) in the complement of the nowhere dense set (often this is used as the definition of "nowhere dense"), and that subinterval cannot be "filled up" by simply adding (i.e. union) a measure zero set to the nowhere dense set.
